# Sliding up DIV container

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How to make a sliding up horizontal DIV container using jquery? So far I have the below-provided code. The problem is that the content of `<h1 id="filter_content">Content</h1>` is initially not hidden. Also I've seen very nice looking sliding up menus, something like the first screenshot [here](http://www.zabbix.com/screenshots.php). So, when user clicks on +, the content slides up. Where can I actually find a sample code or some example?

```
<div id="filter">
  <h1>Filter</h1><br>
</div>
<h1 id="filter_content">Content</h1>

<script>
$('#filter').click(function() {
    if ($("#filter").is(":hidden")) {
          $("#filter_content").show("slow");
        } else {
          $("#filter_content").slideUp("slow");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hiya [**working demo click here**](http://jsfiddle.net/PnLmQ/) **or** [**Initially hidden demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/PnLmQ/1/)

using `slideToggle` API: good read http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/ Will do the trick for the exact behavior you are looking for.

**code**

```
$('#filter').click(function() {

          $("#filter_content").slideToggle("slow");

    });
​
```

Comment: Ok,now it works. But how do I make filter_content initially hidden?

Comment: Oh, I see: style="display:none;"